# Extract specific records from a text file and save to a new file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a txt file which contain thousands of receipts info.
There are two types:

- Regular receipts

[image: REGULAR RECEIPT]

- Summary receipts

[image]

I need to get all Summary receipts and it's contents only and itsand write them into a new file.

The following is what I've done so far, but what it does is just copying everything to a new file.

```
filtered = []
with open("sample.txt", "r+") as file: 
    for line in file:
        filtered.append(line.split(""" 
                    Company Name
                      A CITY         
                    Name of CITY              
                     Tin:00000     
                      #10000      
            N#00108235 Cashier ID#0000 
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                Report(X-Report)         
        """))

    outputfile = open("output.txt","w") 
    for lines in filtered:
        outputfile.write(str(lines))
```

I'm quite new to python and tips or guidance is much appreciated. TIA

Comment: So your problem is how do you identify summary receipts from regular ones?

Comment: Yes, identify summary receipts and save them into a separate text file.

Comment: Do they have all the same formats? One for regular and one for recipe?

Comment: look into regex. `import re` and then use the regex format to group the main content(items) of the receipt. Can you edit the question to show what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

do you only need to seperate them according to the type?
Simple solution as per your explaination is to read the contents of the file and find the word "SUMMARY OF CHARGES" in that file, if found then save the content to a new file.
regex for anything with a word `abc` in it will be `.*abc.*`
the code would be something like this if you have single file for single receipt.

```
import re
with open("sample.txt","r") as sfile:
   cont=sfile.read()
if (re.match(".*SUMMARY OF CHARGES.*",cont)):
   with open("outfile.txt","w") as outfile:
      outfile.write(cont)
```

To seperate the contents of individual receipts, you can use the regex groups. make the regex in such a way that it'll only keep a single receipt, then make a group (your_regex)* then iterate over that group to get all the matching receips.

Answer (score 0):

First we can split the entire file into a list of recipe like this.

```py
with open("sample.txt", "r+") as file: 
    receipts = file.read()

# We convert it to a list of receipts
receipts = receipts.split("- - - - -") #<=== This should be tweak to ensure that we split all receipt. You can also use "FROM THE DATE  PERMIT TO USE"
```

Then we filter hour list we something that is unique in recipe list.

```py
my_filter = lambda receipt: "SUMMARY OF CHARGE" in receipt
summaries = list(filter(my_filter, receipts)) 

with open("out.txt", "a") as outfile:
    for summary in summaries:
        outfile.write(summary)
```